# .htaccess breaking my site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching

I'm trying to optimize my site using Google Analytic's site speed suggestions and one of the suggestions it gave me was to Leverage Browser Caching in my .htaccess file.

After doing some research on .htaccess I found that my site didn't have one. I created my own .htaccess and filled it with the below text:

```
AllowOverride All

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

I uploaded it to my site, and now when loading any of the pages on my site I get an error page that says the following:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable 
to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, [no address given] and inform them 
of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may 
have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Any idea what might be causing this? I'm new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove or comment out this line

```
AllowOverride All
```

As this directive isn't allowed in htaccess. It is only allowed in Apache config, hence presence of this line is causing internal 500 error.